# How to include Babel runtime to transformed code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a single ES6 file:

```
function* children(element) {
   for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; ++i) {
       yield element.children[i];
   }
}

for (const child of children(document.body)) {
    console.log(child);
}
```

I use Babel to transform it to ES5 via JavaScript API:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
const babelPresetES2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');
const babelPresetES2016 = require('babel-preset-es2016');
const babelPresetES2017 = require('babel-preset-es2017');

const es6code = '...'; // Actual code fetch is skipped to make the example short

const es5code = babel.transform(es6code, {
    presets: [babelPresetES2015, babelPresetES2016, babelPresetES2017]
}).code;
```

After transform I get this code:

```
"use strict";

var _marked = [children].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);

function children(element) {
    var i;
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function children$(_context) {
        while (1) {
            switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
                case 0:
                    i = 0;

                case 1:
                    if (!(i < element.children.length)) {
                        _context.next = 7;
                        break;
                    }

                    _context.next = 4;
                    return element.children[i];

                case 4:
                    ++i;
                    _context.next = 1;
                    break;

                case 7:
                case "end":
                    return _context.stop();
            }
        }
    }, _marked[0], this);
}

var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = children(document.body)[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var child = _step.value;

        console.log(child);
    }
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
            _iterator.return();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the transformed code refers to the variables that are defined neither in the code nor in the browser environment: `regeneratorRuntime` and `Symbol`. As a result it doesn't work in browser.

How to transform ES6 code to ES5 using Babel so that all required variables are declared, no excess variables are declared (to not bloat the code) and the code is ready to work in browser?

Or at least how to make all dependancies added by Babel be listed in the result code with `require` function?

Comment: you'll need the runtime "helper" javascript file loaded in a script tag in your web page perhaps

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I get this file? Is it too heavy because it contains declarations that are not used in my code (Map, Set, Promise, etc.)?

Comment: FWIW, `Symbol` is globally available in newer browsers. If you want to run your code in an environment that does not support it, you have to use https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ (which also includes the regenerator runtime).

Comment: @FelixKling `Symbol` is not widely enough supported to use it without a polyfill. 1) Browsers don't understand `require`. How to include the polyfill code to the transformed bundle? 2) If do it using Browserify, the whole amount of polyfills will be bundled to the result code which is excessive.

Comment: @Finesse so polyfill only what you need https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately yes, I have to find what polyfills does Babeled code need and add them by myself :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Babel [transform-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime) plugin. It makes Babel generate such code that `require()`s Babel helpers (including `regeneratorRuntime`) instead of adding them to the code.

```
// ...
const babelPluginTransformRuntime = require('babel-plugin-transform-runtime');

const es5code = babel.transform(es6code, {
    presets: [babelPresetES2015, babelPresetES2016, babelPresetES2017],
    plugins: [babelPluginTransformRuntime]
}).code;
```

But after doing so, the transformed code will contain no Babel helpers so you need to install the helpers as an NPM dependency:

```
npm install --save babel-runtime
```

And use a JS bundler like [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org), [Webpack](http://webpack.js.org) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org) to concatenate the code and the helpers all together.